# How do I kill loops in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, loops

I've been writing/debugging in Xcode and every now and then I accidentally create a loop that I can't stop. Unpasuing debuging and rebuilding (and Go-ing) doesn't help, nor does any of the normal Ctrl-C stuff that I'd use on a normal CLI. The only thing that does the trick is quiting Xcode.

Odd question, I know, but any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you're running in the simulator, you can just quit the simulator.

XCode doesn't execute your iPhone code, it installs it in the Simulator which runs it. Or it it installs it on the device which runs it.

I think there's a big red button when the simulator is running which will kill it. You shouldn't have to quit XCode at all for something like this.

Comment: The big red button looks like a stop sign or a ping-pong paddle.

Answer (score 2):

Kill the running app using "Activity Monitor". Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the phone, hold down the home key.

Answer (score -1):

You could try doing a "`kill -9 <pid>`" from the command line.  You'll just need to figure out the process ID using "`ps -ef`".